# select2 widget selected will updated other select2

Tags: yii2

Hi all i am newbie in yii2 need your advise
i use select2 widget, when i selected value it will throw another value that i had set in array before. so how can i do this in yii2. so far i doing this.i have try using jquery function using pluginevents in select2 but still stuck..here is my code

```
<?= $idnpwp = ArrayHelper::map(Mfwp::find()->all(),"id", "npwp", "nama_wp");?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'npwp')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'language' => 'id',
    'data' => $idnpwp,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a NPWP ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
    ],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "change" => 'function(data) { 
            var data_id = $(this).val();
            $("input#target").val($(this).val());
        }',
    ]
]);  
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'nama_wp')->textInput(['id' => 'target']) ?>
```

how can i insert 'nama_wp' that already set in array into field nama_wp
thx for helping

Comment: unclear what you are asking which array are you talking about here ? what i understand from your code is that when we change the option in the select2 the onchange function will get the current selected value and then insert that value in the input `target` which is of type text.

Comment: $idpwp is an array. Array content id, npwp, nama_wp.. How can if i select value in npwp form, nama_wp will be filled in nama_wp form field..

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to change the

```
<?= $idnpwp = ArrayHelper::map(Mfwp::find()->all(),"id", "npwp", "nama_wp");?>
```

to

```
<?php $idnpwp = ArrayHelper::map(Mfwp::find()->all(),"id", "npwp", "nama_wp");?>
```

The you need to access the current value of the select2 via `data.currentTarget.value`, so change the code for `change` to the following.

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'npwp')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'language' => 'id',
    'data' => $idnpwp,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a NPWP ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
    ],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "change" => 'function(data) { 
            var data_id = data.currentTarget.value;
            $("#target").val(data_id );
        }',
    ]
]);  
?>
```