# Select2 widget Get ID and updated other input Text in Yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2

**create form select2. when selected, change other inputText from same sql table**

hi all need your advice in yii2 framework..
i have an sql table name:mfwp.its contain id,id_mfwp,npwp,nama_wp and alamat_wp
i use select2 widget to find npwp, after user selecting npwp it will throw the id into inputText name:nama_wp(will retrieve nama_wp from mfwp sql table) and inputText:alamat_wp(will retrieve alamat_wp from mfwp sql table).here is my function in MfwpController.

```
public function actionLists($id){

    $countPosts = MFwp::find()
    ->where(['id' => $id])
    ->count();

    $posts = Mfwp::find()
    ->where(['id' => $id])
    ->orderBy('id DESC')
    ->all();


    if($countPosts>0){
        foreach($posts as $post){
        echo "<option value='".$post->id."'>".$post->nama_wp."</option>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<option>-</option>";
    }

}
```

and here is my view form

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;
use \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use \app\models\Mfwp;
use \app\models\Pejabat;
use kartik\widgets\Select2;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\web\View;

<?= $idnpwp = ArrayHelper::map(Mfwp::find()->all(),"id", "npwp", "nama_wp");?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'npwp')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'language' => 'id',
    'data' => $idnpwp,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a NPWP ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
    ],

    'pluginEvents' => [
        'Change'=>'
        $.post("'.Url::to(['mfwp/lists']).'&id="+$(this).val(),function(data){
        $("#target").html(data);
        });
        '
    ]

]);

?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'nama_wp')->textInput(['id' => 'target']) ?>
```

iam already try just for 1 inputText but still stuck. when i reload my console browser, its appears an error :SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

i try navigate to http://bla-bla.oke/mfwp/lists?id=1 and show something like this :

First try before modify the code:
raw data:

```
<option value='1'>DARIA VARIA</option>null
```

why show null?and then

JSON : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

also iam try modify the pluginevents of select2 become like this :

```
       'pluginEvents' => [
        'change'=>'function(data) { 
            var data_id = data.currentTarget.value;

            },$.post("'.Url::to(['mfwp/lists']).'&id="+val(data_id),function(data){
            $("#target").val(data.nama_wp);
            });',
      ]
```

and the actionList function in controller become like this

```
    public function actionLists($id)
{   


    $posts = Mfwp::find()
    ->where(['id' => $id])
    ->asArray()
    ->orderBy('id DESC')
    ->one();
    Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
    return $posts;


}
```

in console browser still and still occure error its appears an error :SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

if i navigate to http://bla-bla.oke/mfwp/lists?id=1 :
After i modified controller and view form pluginevents in select2, a table showing in browser,all field in mfwp sql table has retrieved. either in JSON or raw data.

but the value still dont appear in inputText nama_wp in form..

thx for giving advice..

**Updated solution from mr omar :**

ive changed pluginevents become like this :

```
        'pluginEvents' => [
        'change'=>'function(event){
            var data_id = event.currentTarget.value;
            $.post("'.Url::to(['mfwp/lists']).'?id="+data_id,function(data){
            $("input#namas").val(data.nama_wp);$("#alamats").val(data.alamat_wp)
            });
        }'
      ]
```

and i changed function in controller become like this :

```
public function actionLists($id)
{   


    $posts = Mfwp::find()
    ->where(['id' => $id])
    ->asArray()
    ->orderBy('id DESC')
    ->one();
    Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
    return $posts;


}
```

**its work great, thx my friend.. **

Comment: it is totally unclear what you are asking, is this related to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189617/select2-widget-selected-will-updated-other-select2 , please be specific what problem are you having here , and about the `null` when do you get `null` ? after you change the option of the drop-down `npwp` ?

Comment: Yes omar..its related to first question..i want when user select value in select2 field then next inputText will be filled with nama_wp automatically..i get null if i navigate my browser to that link..its null part of problem showing nama_wp value in next inputText?

Comment: i want when user select value in select2 field then next inputText will be filled with nama_wp automatically..my real problem is when i refresh that form select2 just appears symbol plugin loading..when i inspect using console browser the error is missing ) after argument list.i realize its something wrong with jquery code in pluginevents select2 but never know where it is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing the event is `change` and not `Change`, so change it accordingly.
About the problem, your problem is here

```
$.post("'.Url::to(['mfwp/lists']).'&id="+$(this).val(),function(data){
```

you are appending the query string with `&` rather than `?` which is the reason when you navigate on changing the option the `id` is not passed to the page/action.

Change it to

```
$.post("'.Url::to(['mfwp/lists']).'?id="+$(this).val(),function(data){
```

Apart from the suggestion above you have several errors in your code,  you should fix them for example the second part where you say that you have changed the event for the select2 is also incorrect

```
'pluginEvents' => [
        'change'=>'function(data) { 
            var data_id = data.currentTarget.value;

            },$.post("'.Url::to(['mfwp/lists']).'&id="+val(data_id),function(data){
            $("#target").val(data.nama_wp);
            });',
      ]
```

If these errors are just because of adding here manually then you should always copy paste the code here as is rather than manually writing here so that the actual reason can be spotted.

**Update**

I thought you will spot the error in the code as i already mentioned that it is not correct. But anyway you should change the above code to the following to work correctly

```
'pluginEvents' => [
    'change'=>'function(event){
        var data_id = event.currentTarget.value;
        $.post("'.Url::to(['mfwp/lists']).'?id="+data_id, function(data){
            $("#target").html(data);
        });
    }'
]
```

Comment: Ive already change & with ? .but error still same : missing ) after argument list. I am not manually typing, i copy it from visual code.

Comment: @SuhariAdi i know it wont work if you wont read carefully what i said in the end of my answer, see the update part

Comment: Thank you my brother.. I ve found the answer just copy your code and use second modify in function controller and plugin events. Its work great..i will updated my thread..may allah swt blessed your knowledge..